# How to retrieve data using Mongoose and node.js from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to retrieve document mongoDB using `mongoose and Node.js` as per user input. I am explaining my `collection schema` below.

```
{
  zone_list: [{
    zone: NORTH,
    state_list: [{    
      state: DELHI,
      location_list: [{
        location: NEW DELHI,
        task_list: [{
          user_pkId: 5c407834953d7f420d56f866,
          front_end_manager_name: SONAL,
          collection_manager: "",
          area_collection_manager: ASHIS JENA,
          loan_accounts_assigned: [{
            allocated_to: FIELD,
            lk_loan_account_id: LK0000015094,
            cl_contract_id: LAI-00016881,
            customer_name: REET INFOTECH,
            customer_bank_name: YES BANK,
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },{
      state: JK,
      location_list: [{
        location: Sree Nagar,
        task_list: [{
          user_pkId: 5c407834953d7f420d56f867,
          front_end_manager_name: SONAL,
          collection_manager: "",
          area_collection_manager: ASHIS JENA,
          loan_accounts_assigned: [{
            allocated_to: FIELD,
            lk_loan_account_id: LK0000015094,
            cl_contract_id: LAI-00016881,
            customer_name: REET INFOTECH,
            customer_bank_name: Corporate BANK,
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  },{
    zone: EAST,
    state_list: [{    
      state: Odisha,
      location_list: [{
        location: Bhubaneswar,
        task_list: [{
          user_pkId: 5c407834953d7f420d56f868,
          front_end_manager_name: SONAL,
          collection_manager: "",
          area_collection_manager: ASHIS JENA,
          loan_accounts_assigned: [{
            allocated_to: FIELD,
            lk_loan_account_id: LK0000015094,
            cl_contract_id: LAI-00016881,
            customer_name: REET INFOTECH,
            customer_bank_name: SBI BANK,
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Here I have the above one document where it contains multiple zone,state etc. I need to fetch the corresponding record as per `zone,state,locations...etc`. I am using the query like below.

```
var zone = req.body.zone;
var allction = db.model("Allocation", alloc);
allction.connection.find({zone: zone}, function(err, docs) {
   if (!err) {
      res.send(docs);
   }
})
```

But here I am not getting the expected output. I need using `zone` input I should get the related record similarly using `zone and state` I should get the corresponding output.

Comment: can you also add, what is the out put you expecting [doc] and what you getting currently?

Comment: hey check in the channel once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, as per your questation, you want to find the zone first from the doc.

you can do something like this using [`positional operator($)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/):

```
allction.connection.find({"zone_list.zone":zone},{projection:{
"zone_list.$":1
//list other fields what you want to select or project
}}).toArray(function(err,docs){
        if (!err) {
            res.send(docs);
        }
})
```

also, if you want to ry with aggregate query will be more like this:

```
allction.collection
  .aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    { $unwind: "$zone_list" },
    { $unwind: "$zone_list.state_list" },
    { $unwind: "$‌​zone_list.state_list.location_list" },
    {
      $match: {
        zone: zone,
        state: state,
        location: location
      }
    }
  ])
  .toArray((err, docs) => {});
```

Comment: its throwing this `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` error.

Comment: updated the answer, can you retry once again and let me know?

Comment: Using the updated code its retrieving total document. I need to fetch the array of data as per zone.

Comment: @subhra my bad, instead of select it takes `projection`. updated once again, please have a look.

Comment: Ok its working as expected but if lets say I need to again filter as per zone and state. Then Can you just help me for the query.

Comment: can you try with: inside find query: `{"zone_list.state_list. state":"DELHI"}` .
and inside peojection: `{"zone_list.state_list.$":1}`  .
let me know, if works, will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187031/discussion-between-saikat-chakrabortty-and-subhra).